# Pylons user authentication roll our own or openid or alternatives?

Tags: python, pylons

what is the current state of user authentication?  is it good to go with openid or another alternative, or we still have to write our own user/password?

Comment: What is this question about? Auth libraries? Whether to use OpenID?

Comment: weather to use openid or another system (is there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:  [Pylons authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601334/pylons-authentication)

But, the direct answer to your question:

You could use RPX along with openid as mentioned on [Tony Landis' blog](http://tonylandis.com/python/openid-db-authentication-in-pylons-is-easy-with-rpx/)